# How to convert digit to character in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to find the simplest way to convert a digit (0..9) into the respective character '0'..'9' in Kotlin.

My initial attempt was to write the following code:

```
fun convertToCharacter() {
    val number = 0

    val character = number.toChar()
    println(character)
}
```

Of course, after running, I quickly saw that this produces \u0000, and not '0' like I expected. Then, remembering from how to do this in Java, I modified the code to add '0', but then this would not compile.

```
fun convertToCharacter() {
    val number = 0

    val character = number.toChar() + '0'
    println(character)
}
```

What is the appropriate way to convert a number into its respective character counterpart in Kotlin? Ideally, I'm trying to avoid pulling up the ASCII table to accomplish this (I know I can add 48 to the number since 48 -> '0' in ASCII).

Comment: `'0' + number`. The order matters: `number + '0'` won't compile.

Answer (score 6):

```
val character = '0' + number
```

is the shortest way, given that the number is in range 0..9

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, probably the easiest way to convert an `Int` to the `Char` representation of that same digit is to add 48 and call `toChar()`:

```
val number = 3
val character = (number + 48).toChar()
println(character) // prints 3
```

If you don't want to have the magic 48 number in your program, you could first parse the number to a `String` and then use `toCharArray()[0]` to get the `Char` representation:

```
val number = 3
val character = number.toString().toCharArray()[0]
println(character) // prints 3
```

Edit: in the spirit of the attempt in your question, you can do math with `'0'.toInt()` and get the result you were expecting:

```
val number = 7
val character = (number + '0'.toInt()).toChar()
println(number) // prints 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin stdlib provides this function since [1.5.0](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/digit-to-char.html).

```kotlin
fun Int.digitToChar(): Char
```

> Returns the Char that represents this decimal digit. Throws an exception if this value is not in the range 0..9.

> If this value is in 0..9, the decimal digit Char with code '0'.code + this is returned.

Example

```kotlin
println(5.digitToChar()) // 5
println(3.digitToChar(radix = 8)) // 3
println(10.digitToChar(radix = 16)) // A
println(20.digitToChar(radix = 36)) // K
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `0.toString()` instead of `0.toChar()` ? If you are specifically after single digits, then `0.toString()[0]` will give you a `Char` type

Answer (score 1):

You can use an **extension** like this:

```
fun Int.toReadableChar(): Char {
    return ('0'.toInt() + this).toChar()
}
```

You can apply this to any other class you want :)

**Example:**

```
println(7.toReadableChar())
```

```
>> 7
```